# How to move marker when lat long changes in Google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

in my android application I am receiving the latitude and longitude from `JSON` and I have pointed it in Google map using marker but I want to move the marker when the latitude and longitude changes like `GPS` tracking?? Please help me here is my source code,.........

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {


            List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

            // Date a = new Date();
            // a.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()-(60*60*1000));
            // Log.e("onehourback",""+a);*/
            // ------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Log.e("object",""+object);
                    /*
                     * try { array.add(jarray.getJSONObject(i));
                     * 
                     * Log.e("array",""+array); } catch (JSONException e) {
                     * e.printStackTrace(); }
                     */
                    latvalue = object.getString("Latitude");
                    longvalue = object.getString("Longitude");
                    latt = Double.parseDouble(latvalue);
                    lng = Double.parseDouble(longvalue);
                    Log.e("lat", "" + latt);
                    Log.e("lon", "" + lng);

                    Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt, lng))); 
                    markers.add(marker1);

                    Log.e("asdf",";lkj"+markers);

                    /*
                     * for(int j=0; j < 1;j++) {
                     * 
                     * 
                     * 
                     * 
                     * }
                     */
                }
            }
            // }
            return true;

            // ------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // dialog.cancel();
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        /*
         * adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); if(result == false)
         * Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
         * "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         */
    }

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
    mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt, lng))
            .title("WePOP"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (mMap != null) {
        // setUpMap();
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0
                        .getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(
                        new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0
                                .getLongitude())).title("WePOP"));

                // mMap.addMarker(new
                // MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position(
                // new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Lat")),
                // Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Long")))));
                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Remove older MArker and add new one MaRKER

Comment: @MD:can you please give me a sample code please

Answer (score 1):

From your current code you are simply overriding a marker on top of another. To avoid this simply clear the old marker and draw a new one,

```
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()); 
                    // clear the marker here
                    mMap.clear();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("WePOP")); 

                    //   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position( new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Lat")), Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Long"))))); 
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15)); 


                }
```

**UPDATE:**

For keeping track of multiple markers the best way would be creating a marker array and load them after the location change.

```
   // first create a maker array
   List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

   // inside doInBackground() add the markers into the list from JSON
   Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng))); 
   markers.add(marker);
```

Now you can keep the markers from JSON and add the new location marker

```
  public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 
    // clear the marker here
    mMap.clear();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()); 
    // check if marker1 is set or available in markers array and load the old marker first
    ............
    // now load the newest marker from location or save them into the markers array for further use
    Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("WePOP")); 
    markers.add(marker2);

   }
```

Comment: If I clear the marker the marker points only the current location but in my application  I want to show the current location and the latitude longitude from JSON also ,So if I clear the marker its not showing the latitude and longitude.

Comment: yes actually its a tracking application  show while the screen opens  it want  to point the current location and the Latitude and Longitude from JSON  using marker and if the Latitude and longitude changes the marker should move

Comment: Prokash Sarkar :I tried by creating  the array list for the set of markers  and plotted the markers as you given above but the app get crashed can you please help me