# Move marker with gps in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I want to make move of the marker in `GOOGLE MAP` while `gps` location changes just like in `UBER` app. I have found some solutions but unable to solve my issue. The solutions are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31555261/6854117) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31912951/6854117)

Below is my `onLocationChange()` method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("I am here");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

**Update 1 (Re-edited)**

For more understanding i am adding some more code, but first i want to tell that i am using tabs in my app. The very first `tab` is of my map. So i am using fragments for it.

```
public class MyLocation extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener{

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker=null;
TextView tv_loc;
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(view != null)
    {
        ViewGroup viewGroupParent = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
        if(viewGroupParent !=null)
        {
            viewGroupParent.removeView(viewGroupParent);
        }
    }
    try{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_location,container, false);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
         /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        return  view;
    }

    // inflat and return the layout
    //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_location, container, false);

    tv_loc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if(mGoogleApiClient !=null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);


    if(mCurrLocationMarker!=null){
        mCurrLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);
    }else{
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                .title("I am here"));
    }

    tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    /*double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("I am here");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)).draggable(true);

    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mCurrLocationMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(lattitude,longitude));

    tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }*/
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    /*super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);*/
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(mGoogleApiClient == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                //finish();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: try `mGoogleMap.clear()` instead of `mCurrLocationMarker.remove()`

Comment: Tried it but no use

Comment: Quick question, where is this method? In an Activity, Service, Application? If in an Activity, does it work until you get back into the activity, or just not work at all? We need to see more code to really help you out. Mainly where this method is located.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42778943/7399521

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use below code to update position of the Marker

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);


    if(mCurrLocationMarker!=null){
        mCurrLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);
    }else{
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                                .title("I am here");
    }

    tv_loc.append("Lattitude: " + lattitude + "  Longitude: " + longitude);
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

You don't need to clear map every time. You can do it by Marker object that is returned when adding Marker to Map.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried your code but still the marker is on the same position while the blue dot is moving. The pin should set on the blue dot when it moves

Comment: Can you please check your onLocationChanged Event is called? also the blue pin is of default map and they may use different logic for location change. You can check setPostion method by hard coding the values and check if position is changed or not. I tried the same and it is changing.

Comment: `stop location updates` this stops the location to update so i think that's why marker is not moved. It's my thinking may be i am wrong

Comment: Moreover `onLocationChange` method is called every time. You can see my update code as well

Comment: Can you please try with Removing the code under stop Location update. And than. If still not than Do upload your whole Activity code if possible. Will have clear idea why it is not being updated

Comment: By Reviewing your code I found that, You are removing Location updates on Location changed event. For the first time It will call Location change Event It will add Marker to Map and in next line it will removeLocation update. so now the onLocation changed event will never called again. Ultimately your onLocation change event is called only once so there will not be situation in which your marker position updated. Just remove the lines to removeLocationUpdate and you will see marker updating the location. Let me know if still there is issue.

Comment: I have tried already and it works but the text on the top keep coming and filling up the above line, i.e. the text view of latitude and longitude keeps on displaying again and again while the previous one still shows.

Comment: One thing i want to ask, the as location update is running then why the blue dot moves from one place to another as my device is place still and it's not moving. Is it normal to behave a gps like that. Moreover the moving of marker is not far from the original location.

Comment: It is task of fused API that you have used. It depend on your location as well. If you are in open air than it will be more accurate. If you are around metal area like in Lift or something than it will less accurate. Still You can set Priority in Location request for more accurate result. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First of All implement  LocationListener in your Activity then

if you need to show only one Marker(update position of Marker), use this :

```
private Marker currentPositionMarker = null;

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

      LatLng  latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

        // mMap.clear(); // Call if You need To Clear Map
        if (currentPositionMarker == null)
            currentPositionMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                    .position(latLng)
                    .zIndex(20));
        else 
            currentPositionMarker.setPosition(latLng);


        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

or if you want to add a new marker every time :

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                .position(latLng)
                .zIndex(20));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

if location was changed rapidly, it would take a couple of seconds for your app to update its location marker

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using CameraPosition, googleMap.animateCamera and marker movement animation using linear interpolator.

You can take a look at this tutorial [here](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3) and the respective github [page](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/blob/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/docs/part3.md).

This tutorial uses google maps v2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

implement `LocationListener ,GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener` in your map activity and then use location change Listener

```
       @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) { 
        //mMap.clear //if you want refresh map remove comment
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude =location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); //your_text_view.settext(latitude+","+longtitudde)

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.destination_marker)).position(latLng).title(maping_status));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    }
```

Comment: Tried, the marker does moves and every time it moves the previous one still shows, moreover i am using a text view that is showing me the current `latitude` and `longitude`. So the text view keep on repeating one by one while the previous one is still there.

Comment: you use marker clear option like `mMap.clear()` . add that above code  before get lat long from my location.

Comment: i hope this will help you @faisal1208

Comment: and add thet inner method like `your_text_view.settext(latitude+","+longtitudde)` **add after get lat long from current location** in above method

Comment: i edit my post for what you like http://stackoverflow.com/a/42778943/7399521 **remove i mentioned command** i hope you understand @faisal1208

Comment: Can't understand what you said, and what changes you made? I have posted my whole code kindly see it

Comment: remove onLocationchanged rather then use my code bro @faisal1208

Comment: It says 'GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener is deprecated'. Moreover no marker or text is showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138092/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-akash-pasupathi).

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to animate just call this method (**animateMarker**) with previous location and new location along with Marker object

```
private Marker mCurrentMarker;
private float ZOOMLEVEL=18.0f;
private LatLng previousLatLon;
private Handler mLocalHandler;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,final LatLng fromPosition) {


        final long duration = 500;
        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        mLocalHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                marker.setPosition(toPosition);
                marker.setAnchor(Constants.MAPANCHOR, Constants.MAPANCHOR);
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toPosition, ZOOMLEVEL));
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    mLocalHandler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                }
            }
        });
        previousLatLon=toPosition;// reassign the previous location to current location
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Answer Will help you.instead of gps use Google Fused Api [Read Documentation Here For Fused Api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)   and Read this Answer 
    [how To Make Bus Marker Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687776/how-to-make-bus-moving-on-google-map/42687850#42687850)

try this tutorial link for better understanding [Fused Api Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

Answer (score 0):

In manifest add these lines

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and then use this class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleMap mgoogleMap;
GoogleApiClient mgoogleApi;
Context context;
Marker marker;
LocationRequest locationrequest;
public static final int map=1111;
public static final int coarse=1112;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (googleServiceAvalable()) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        checkReadPermission();
        checkCoarsePermission();
        initMap();
    } else {

    }

}
public boolean googleServiceAvalable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isavailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isavailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isavailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isavailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "cant connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mgoogleMap = googleMap;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    mgoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if(checkCoarsePermission() && checkReadPermission()){
        mgoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mgoogleApi.connect();
    }else {
        checkReadPermission();
        checkCoarsePermission();
    }
}

private void goToLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int i) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, i);
    mgoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

    if(marker !=null){
        marker.remove();
    }

    MarkerOptions options =new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Test")
            .draggable(true)
            .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude ));
    marker= mgoogleMap.addMarker(options);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationrequest = new LocationRequest().create();
    locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationrequest.setInterval(1000);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mgoogleApi, locationrequest, this);
    Toast.makeText(context,"Location Connected and ready to publish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Location Connection Suspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Location Connection Failed"+connectionResult.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location==null){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Cant Find User Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else {
        LatLng ll=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        goToLocation(ll.latitude,ll.longitude,18);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public boolean checkReadPermission() {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Read Internal Storage permission required to display images!!!");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, map);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, map);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public boolean checkCoarsePermission() {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Read Internal Storage permission required to display images!!!");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, coarse);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, coarse);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case map:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You have to give permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case coarse:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You have to give permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;


    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the solution, hope this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ will help you. I've used this in one of my apps and it helps animating the marker from one location to other location. 
Source code can be grabbed here https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689.

You might need to add rotation to your marker to show the exact direction of the marker. Following is the block of code that I'm using to find bearing.

```
    private float bearingBetweenLatLngs(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
        Location beginL = convertLatLngToLocation(begin);
        Location endL = convertLatLngToLocation(end);

        return beginL.bearingTo(endL);
    }
```