# Google map is not updating LatLong with location change

Tags: android, android-location

to start with, I am completely confused with various api's available for location and map. So, I even dont know if the code is optimal for sdk 27.(I have minimum sdk 24 set.)

The problem is this piece of code shows the current location well and fine, butand the map gets updated when the location is changed. But, that is not reflected in location. See, the polyline drawn from `LatLong` does not follow the current location.

Also, I am trying to implement `FusedLocationProviderClient` but thats probably not the case here.

Any help will be very welcome.

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    //Color stroke = new Color(222.0,135.0, 135.0,174.0);

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public GoogleMap getMap() {
        return mMap;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        double latitude;
        double longitude;


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                    {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        } else {

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (location == null) {
                latitude = 0.0;
                longitude = 0.0;
            } else {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

            }
            latlang.Lat = latitude;
            latlang.Lang = longitude;

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(18).build();


            double angle = Math.toRadians(93.833);

            Point cPoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
            System.out.println("mPoint X"+  cPoint.x);
            System.out.println("mPoint Y"+  cPoint.y);
            Point mPoint = new Point();

            //Azimuth Pos only
            double lat_azi = 2*Math.sin(angle)+cPoint.y;
            double long_azi = 2*Math.cos(angle)+cPoint.x;

            LatLng nat_azi =mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(mPoint);

            //private List<Point> mPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(nat_azi)
                    .anchor(0.5f,0.5f)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sun_pos_icon))
                );
            Marker marker_loc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon))
            );

            mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(lat_azi, long_azi), new LatLng(latitude, longitude), new LatLng(0,0))
                    .width(15)
                    .color(Color.MAGENTA));

            PathOfSun.getTime();


            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true); // true to enable
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have processing in your 'onLocationChanged' callback where you'll redraw lines/shapes.  Note you'll have to erase the previous and draw a new one on each location change (assuming that's what you want) which means maintaining a reference to the polyline, e.g.  See LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates() - if using fused.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below link for Updating Marker position on the Map.

[Move marker with gps in google map android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576534/move-marker-with-gps-in-google-map-android/42668309#42668309)

Comment: Thnks for your reply, but this is one point of confusion: FusedLocationProviderApi is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, That is deperected now. But that is just for reference according to specific requirements. If you want continously updated location, you need to remove that code from snippet. Also alternative for FusedLocationProviderAPI is FusedLocationProviderClient.

Comment: Thnaks for your reference too. I am very stuck on the map and location, and dont actually know how to enable that in a fragment.

Comment: I Recommand you to use MapView rather than MapFragment.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-mapview-example-tutorial/
Proabbly it will clear your issues with Map in Fragment