# How to use locationManager with Maps SDK for Android simulating an uber app like map

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to use locationManager with Maps SDK for Android simulating an uber app like map
Follows my class that takes the location but it returns a latitude and longitude with values 0.0

```
class LocationUtil(context: Context) {

    private val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    private var locationListener: LocationListener? = null

    val locationStateFlow = MutableStateFlow(Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    val gpsProviderState = mutableStateOf(false)
    val isStart: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)

    private val locHandlerThread = HandlerThread("LocationUtil Thread")

    init {
        locHandlerThread.start()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun start(minTimeMs: Long = min_time, minDistanceM: Float = min_distance) {

        locationListener().let {
            locationListener = it
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeMs, minDistanceM, it, locHandlerThread.looper)

        }
        gpsProviderState.value = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        isStart.value = true
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun stop() {
        locationListener?.let {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(it)
        }
        isStart.value = false
    }

    private fun locationListener() = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            locationStateFlow.value = location
        }

        @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {
            gpsProviderState.value = true
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
            gpsProviderState.value = false
        }
    }


    companion object {
        const val min_time: Long = 1000L
        const val min_distance: Float = 1.0f
    }

}
```

Below in my activity with the permission request for the location:

```
@Composable
private fun FeatureThatRequiresCameraPermission(multiplePermissionsState: MultiplePermissionsState) {
    if (multiplePermissionsState.allPermissionsGranted) {
        // If all permissions are granted, then show screen with the feature enabled
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val locationUtil = LocationUtil(context)
        locationUtil.start()
        val gpsEnable by locationUtil.gpsProviderState
        val coordenadas by locationUtil.locationStateFlow.collectAsState()

        latitude.value = coordenadas.latitude
        longitude.value = coordenadas.longitude
        Text(text = coordenadas.latitude.toString()+">>"+coordenadas.longitude.toString())

        val singapore = LatLng(latitude.value, longitude.value)
        val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
            position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
        }

        GoogleMap(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxWidth(100f).height(200.dp),
                cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState) {
            Marker(position = LatLng(latitude.value,longitude.value), title = "Marker in Sydney")

        }

    } else {
        Column {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Button(onClick = { multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest() }) {
                Text("Request permissions")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make an uber-like map?

Comment: Have you seen: [Move marker with gps in google map android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42576534/295004)

Comment: This one doesn't show how to do it in  [map-compose](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/index.html) but in java